# Extending Unnamed Types in Go

Tags: go

So the following works:

```
type Individual [][]int
type Population []*Individual
```

What I'm trying to do is add a field to Population so I do the following

```
var p Population
p.Name = "human"
```

So I tried this:

```
type Individual [][]int
type Population struct {
     []*Individual
     Name string
}
```

But it doesn't work for me. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare a name for the field of your struct:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Individual [][]int

type Population struct {
    Individual []*Individual // <- A name for field
    Name       string
}

func main() {
    var p Population
    p.Name = "human"
    fmt.Printf("%+v", p)
}
```

[`playground`](https://play.golang.org/p/bNTd36DrWMW)

```
=> {Individual:[] Name:human}
```

Comment: But then I can't iterate over p. I was hoping that I could do something like `for _, i := range p {...}` rather than `for _, i := range p.Individual {...}`

Comment: @qzvrwxce `range` only supports `slices`, `arrays`, `channels` and `maps`, you can't `range` over struct fields, so `range p.Individual` the only option.